# Out of Memory Exception in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, task-parallel-library

I am using Parallel.ForEach to do my job but got "Out of Memory Exception".

```
Parallel.ForEach(flist, (item) =>
{
    string f1 = item.Split('|')[0];
    string f2 = item.Split('|')[1];
    a = File.ReadAllText(f1);
    b = File.ReadAllText(f2); 
    Consume(a, b);
});
```

`flist`'s size is 351, `a` and `b` are string, each of them has 20kb size. At a certain time, the system memory blown up.

Consume return a string list, usually around 1000 strings in each iteration.

How to deal with it?

Comment: What does Consume do? Is it memory intensive?

Comment: Did you check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977218/parallel-foreach-can-cause-a-out-of-memory-exception-if-working-with-a-enumera?rq=1

Comment: setting maxdegreeofparallelism help?

Comment: It's very possible that you're creating 351 threads at once. Each has a stack of 1MB, plus the memory used by the file text and strings / lists etc. It's not inconceivable that it could run out of memory. Try using `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set to 4, and see if that helps.

Comment: --@Baldrick, I am not sure how to add ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism in the code. Can you modify my code?

Comment: @Love: Added as answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
  Parallel.ForEach(flist, (item) =>
    {
        string f1 = item.Split('|')[0];
        string f2 = item.Split('|')[1];
        a = File.ReadAllText(f1);
        b = File.ReadAllText(f2); 
        Consume(a, b);
    });
```

With:

```
    Parallel.ForEach(flist, 
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
    (item) =>
    {
        string f1 = item.Split('|')[0];
        string f2 = item.Split('|')[1];
        a = File.ReadAllText(f1);
        b = File.ReadAllText(f2); 
        Consume(a, b);
    });
```

This will prevent too many threads being created. Then you can always experiment with higher numbers and see if performance improves.

Comment: I got another error, StackOverflowException after using the code."Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException".

Comment: Do you have a recursion somewhere?

Comment: Yes, Consume itself is deep recursed.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading an entire file into a single string twice per loop.  That's very likely the source of your problem if the file is large.

Comment: No, actually I got the exception after finished several tasks.