# LockBits() Throwing 'Out Of Memory' in Parallel Foreach?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, image-processing, parallel-processing, lockbits

Iam new to the c# and Parallel processing. I am trying to process the bunch of images and i have written methods for processing.And I have added the Parallel foreach loop on imagelist as below

```
    Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(path), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, fileName =>
            {
                List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
                using (Bitmap imageBitmap= new Bitmap(fileName))
                {
                    using (ImageProcessor imageProcessor= new ImageProcessor ())
                    {
                        tempList = imageProcessor.ProcessImage(imageBitmap);
                    }
                }
                if (tempList.Count != 0)
                    allElements.Add(tempList.FirstOrDefault());
            });
```

In one of the method I have used the `LockBits` method to get the `BitMapData` of the image and copying that data to the `byte[]` but method is throwing the exception the code of method is

```
   private byte[] ImageToByteArray(Bitmap b, out int stride)
    {
        object sync = new object();
        BitmapData bd;
        lock (sync)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height);
            bd = b.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);//This line throwing the exception.

            try
            {
                byte[] pxl = new byte[bd.Stride * b.Height];
                Marshal.Copy(bd.Scan0, pxl, 0, bd.Stride * b.Height);
                stride = bd.Stride;
                return pxl;
            }
            finally
            {
                b.UnlockBits(bd);
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to `lock` the code which is using the `LockBits` method so at a time only one thread at a time use the code and hence the memory.

I also tried using the `lock` with call of the methods from parent method like

```
    public List<string> ProcessImage(BitMap image)
    {
        object sync = new object();
        int stride;
        byte[] rawImg;
        using (image)
        {
            lock (sync)
            {
                rawImg = ImageToByteArray(image, out stride);
            }
            processingImg = new ProcessImage(rawImg, image.Width, image.Height);
        }
  }
```

but still the exception is there. The exception isn't give me any stack trace or explanation only Exception message I am getting is `Out Of Memory`.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977218/parallel-foreach-can-cause-a-out-of-memory-exception-if-working-with-a-enumera?answertab=active#tab-top) answer and when i reduced the `MaximumDegreeOfParallelism` it worked correctly.

So basically I wanted to know,
       1) why the code was throwing the `Out Of Memory` exception for more that 2 threads even there is `lock` on the code? 
       2) And is it possible to avoid this exception if I increase the `DegreeOfParallelism`?
Any help would be great.

---

In case of any confusion feel free to comment.

Comment: The `lock` in the `ProcessImage` is useless as you lock on a local object. And to use `using (variable)` is most often highly problematic since you can dispose an object you don't own.

Comment: Bitmap.LockBits will allocate a large chunk of memory. Parallel.ForEach will keep pawning and executing tasks until 2 CPU cores are fully occupied. Each task will load an image in memory and lock its bits. Therefore its assumable that you run out of memory before 2 processor cores are fully occupied.

Try spawning a Task that loads images in a BlockingCollection with a limited capacity of X and 2 consumers that process these prefetched images.

Answer (score 0):

1. The question is how big are images that you want to process. Maybe
   they are just too big. My experience also shows that calling *LockBits* allocates additional amount of memory - effectively it doubles amount of allocated memory. Did you try to process some very small picture?
2. The *lock* in your code does nothing because you are locking on a local variables. If you want to synchronize access to a critical section between threads and you want to do so with *lock* then you have to use an object that is shared between all these threads. In your case *sync* object should be declared as a private field of *ImageProcessor* class.
3. I think that increasing *DegreeOfParallelism* will not help or even
   will make things worse because your code will need more memory to
   process more images.