# How to force an OutOfMemoryException in .Net

Tags: .net

Sometimes it's helpful to get an application into a bad situation to see how it responds.  Things like unplugging the network cable or removing power will show me how resilient my application is and where I have work to do.

To this end, I'm trying to figure out what the fastest way to force an `OutOfMemoryException` in .Net.  Doing it in a simple console application will allow me to inject this scenario into a running application.  There are obviously other things that need to be considered when dealing with `OutOfMemoryExceptions` (e.g. memory fragmentation and how the garbage collector has allocated the different generations) but that's not important for the scope of this experiment.

**Update**
To clarify the purpose of the question, it's important to note that simply throwing an out of memory exception isn't helpful since I want to see how the program will react when the memory pressure is increased.  In essence, I want to stimulate the GC into an aggressive collection mode and monitor how that impacts the performance until the process dies from an out of memory exception.

Comment: A [old question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977218/parallel-foreach-can-cause-a-out-of-memory-exception-if-working-with-a-enumera) might interest you.

Comment: How resilient could an app be to a power loss?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595061/outofmemoryexception-while-populating-memorystream-256mb-allocation-on-16gb-sys

Comment: @Rotem What if it's SkyNet? :D

Comment: @rotem While there's no surefire way to handle a LossOfPowerException, there are things you can do to protect sensitive data (e.g. not caching critical data in a client, writing data to storage more often etc.)

Comment: @MattRuwe In that case an `OutOfMemoryException` might not be the best simulation for that scenario. Killing the `Process` might be closer.

Comment: `throw new OutOfMemoryException()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One example [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception(v=vs.110).aspx)..

> The following example illustrates the OutOfMemoryException exception thrown by a call to the StringBuilder.Insert(Int32, String, Int32) method when the example tries to insert a string that would cause the object's Length property to exceed its maximum capacity

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(15, 15);
      sb.Append("Substring #1 ");
      try {
         sb.Insert(0, "Substring #2 ", 1);
      }
      catch (OutOfMemoryException e) {
         Console.WriteLine("Out of Memory: {0}", e.Message);
      }
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//    Out of Memory: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
```

Further ,it says how to rectify the error.

> Replace the call to the StringBuilder.StringBuilder(Int32, Int32) constructor with a call any other StringBuilder constructor overload. The maximum capacity of your StringBuilder object will be set to its default value, which is Int32.MaxValue.
>
> Call the StringBuilder.StringBuilder(Int32, Int32) constructor with a maxCapacity value that is large enough to accommodate any expansions to the StringBuilder object.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> An OutOfMemoryException exception has two major causes:
>
> - You are attempting to expand a StringBuilder object beyond the length defined by its StringBuilder.MaxCapacity property.
> - The common language runtime cannot allocate enough contiguous memory to successfully perform an operation. This exception can be
>     thrown by any property assignment or method call that requires a
>     memory allocation. For more information on the cause of the
>     OutOfMemoryException exception, see "Out of Memory" Does Not Refer to
>     Physical Memory.
>
>   This type of OutOfMemoryException exception represents a catastrophic failure. If you choose to handle the exception, you
>     should include a catch block that calls the Environment.FailFast
>     method to terminate your app and add an entry to the system event log,
>     as the following example does.

It seems to me the first one with the string builder would be easier.

This works:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(5, 5);
sb.Insert(0, "hello", 2);
```